# Windows Store app sideloading

Tags: deployment, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store, sideloading

I have associate my Windows Store app with the Windows store and I got a "Appname_StoreKey.pfx" key file, and I deleted my temporary key. If I create my app package using this key will my app expires after a month?

Temporary key expires on a month but this StoreKey says it will expire after a year. Please explain any cons of this procedure.
Due to company requirement I can't submit the app to the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test certificates will expire one year (not month) after creating them. Technically you can use these to publish your app, but this is not recommended.
The same is true if you get a [appname]_StoreKey.pfx after associating your app with the store. 
You can view the expiration date in VS, see screenshot.
[image]

This cert is taken to sign your code. The app package signature ensures that the package and contents haven't been modified after they were signed.

When you're not deploying using the store the disadvantage is that during deplyoment, the certificate is not trusted. This is in both cases no matter if you take the testcert or the storekey.pfx. 
Your users are required to first install the certificate. This is something they might not be able to do (missing rights) or don't dare to do (because they're scared).

When you take a closer look, you will find that the issuer name of testcert might look good, and probably looks very strange (long guid) for a StoreKey.pfx . So users who are asked to install the cert might be scared for a reason.

[image]

The best way is to use your own certificate that you created that won't expire too early and that is installed by your IT device management Infrastructure (if you're building a company app for example). This will lead to a struggle-free installation for users.

Using a test certificate is possible technically but not a very "clean solution". 
Also check out this post
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230260(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj835832.aspx